# Filtering thousands of composite keys in EF Core 3

Tags: performance, entity-framework-core, fetch, composite-key

I have the following entity class (I am using Pomelo for MySql provider and EF Core 3.1):

```
public class MyEntity
{
     public int AAA { get; set; }
     public string BBB { get; set; }
     public decimal CCC { get; set; }
}
```

The corresponding MySQL table MyEntity has a composite primary key composed of the two properties AAA and BBB.

Given a list of thousands filter entities of type MyEntity, I must retrieve from the database only the records whose corresponding primary key fetch the filter list.

**My first solution was to try using a predicate** as mentioned in a former thread, and i**t works if the list of filters does not contains too many filter entities, otherwise I get a Stackoverflow exception if the list of filters contains for instance 1 million entities:**

```
// Variable 'filters' contains several thousands of MyEntity objects.
var results = myContext.Set<MyEntity>()
                       .Where(PredicateHelper.FilterEntity(filters))
                       .ToList();
```

Here is the implementation of the predicate methods:

```
 public static class PredicateHelper
 {
     public static Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> False<MyEntity>()
     {
        return f => false;
     }

     public static Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> FilterEntity(List<MyEntity> keys)
     {
         var predicate = PredicateHelper.False<MyEntity>();

         foreach (MyEntity key in keys)
         {
             predicate = predicate.Or(ent => ent.AAA == key.AAA && ent.BBB == key.BBB);
         }

         return predicate;
    }
  }
```

**So I tried another solution using a Where clause with a Contain query inside**, but I get an exception telling me that there is no MySql translation for the query, and **I must evaluate it client-side**. But if I insert a ToList() before the Where clause, it means that the entire set of records will be stored in-memory right?, and I do not want it, how can I solve the issue, thanks in advance for any suggestions?

```
var results = myContext.Set<MyEntity>()
.Where(ent => filters.Contains(new MyEntity()
 {
      AAA = ent.AAA,
      BBB = ent.BBB
 }))
 .ToList();
```

But I get the following exception: The LINQ expression DbSet.Where(c =>__list_0.Contains(new M{ AAA = c.AAA, BBB = c.BBB }))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Comment: With these numbers of elements you have to resort to a stored procedure. Any client-code solution will be hopelessly slow.

Comment: It is not possible with vanilla EFCore. You need extension which works with temporary tables. I can write sample if you are interested in that. Also I think you are trying to do bulk upsert isn't?

Comment: Hi @SvyatoslavDanyliv. Thank you for your response. Indeed, I want to retrieve filtered rows from Database in order to upsert them afterwards. Sure I am very interested in your sample if you have time ? Thank you so much

Comment: Actually answered several times in this area [check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70521626/10646316)